# What is the difference between partition_point and lower_bound?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, partitioning, binary-search

C++11 includes the algorithm [`std::partition_point()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_point). However for all the cases I have tried it gives the same answer as [`std::lower_bound()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound). The only difference being the convenient `T& value` parameter.

Did I miss something or are these two functions doing more or less the same thing?

Comment: You have tried to read e.g. [this `std::partition_point` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_point) and [this `std::lower_bound` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)? There are some (subtle I'll admit) differences in regards to the predicate.

Comment: one is unary predicate and the other is binary predicate. i guess these little differences merited a seperate function

Comment: Another difference is that `std::partition_point` doesn't require the range to be ordered, while `std::lower_bound` does.

Comment: i think both require it to be partitioned while ordered is a subset of partitioned

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't think that is required.  From what I can tell all it requires it needs to be partitioned.  For instance this seems to work: https://wandbox.org/permlink/q4WljInrpwK2POfo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are basically equivalent.  This would be a valid implementation of `lower_bound`:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator, typename T>
ForwardIterator lower_bound(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
    T const& value)
{
    return partition_point(first, last, [&](auto&& elem) {
        return elem < value;
    });
}

template <typename ForwardIterator, typename T, typename Compare>
ForwardIterator lower_bound(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
    T const& value, Compare comp)
{
    return partition_point(first, last, [&](auto&& elem) {
        return comp(elem, value);
    });
}
```

The two algorithms rely upon finding the partition point of a partitioned range, they just take different arguments with which to search (a unary predicate for `partition_point`, vs a value or value and binary predicate for `lower_bound`).

We just typically think of `lower_bound` in the context of sorted range with a binary predicate - even though a fully sorted range with respect to such a predicate is [not a requirement for that algorithm](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms#lower.bound-1).

---

While we're at it, `upper_bound` can also be implemented in terms of `partition_point`, just with the operands flipped and the predicate negated:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator, typename T>
ForwardIterator upper_bound(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
    T const& value)
{
    return partition_point(first, last, [&](auto&& elem) {
        return !(value < elem);
    });
}

template <typename ForwardIterator, typename T, typename Compare>
ForwardIterator upper_bound(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
    T const& value, Compare comp)
{
    return partition_point(first, last, [&](auto&& elem) {
        return !comp(value, elem);
    });
}
```

---

It's weird how differently the two are worded.

[`lower_bound` returns](http://eel.is/c++draft/lower.bound#2) (the `upper_bound` wording is [similar](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.binary.search#upper.bound-2)):

> The furthermost iterator `i` in the range `[first, last]` such that for every iterator `j` in the range `[first, i)` the following corresponding conditions hold: `*j < value` or `comp(*j, value) != false`.

while [`partition_point` returns](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.partitions#17)

> An iterator `mid` such that `all_­of(first, mid, pred)` and `none_­of(mid, last, pred)` are both `true`.

Those phrases are equivalent since the requirement is that the range is partitioned. But it sure doesn't seem that way at first glance.

Comment: Is there any reasons your lambdas don't just use a default-capture `&`? Also, why does your lambda instead capture `comp` by value, is it guaranteed to be copyable? You could handle [`std::binary_search()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) too to make a clean sweep. Anyway, nice answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator I have no idea why I did that - there is no such requirement as far as I can tell.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure adding `const` to the forwarded argument is actually allowed. There's even an active issue about it: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#3031

Comment: @Deduplicator That's about the arguments to the comparison itself. I'm not sure that's related to anything here.

Comment: If you look it through, it makes the point that you the Standard does not quite give the implementation latitude nor mandate to unilaterally make the comparators argument a `const&`, though it may assume the comparator does not change ist arguments. Your implementations of the standard functions accepting a comparator does that though. It's a subtle point which should be emphasized if intended (unlikely) or fixed in the standard.

Comment: @Deduplicator Oh... I see what you mean now. Yep, removing the `const`s.

Comment: @Deduplicator BTW, the requirement on a comparator isn't just that it acts "like a const function", it must act as a pure functional (aka applicative) function, it cannot change any meaningful property, the only meaningful property in case of multisets being the result of the comparator. That requirement is implicit in any algebraic specification of a concept (f.ex. the anti symmetric requirement).

Answer (score 4):

They both use a binary search algorithm (for random access iterator).

- `std::lower_bound` requires that the range to be <strike>sorted according to (binary) predicate</strike> partitioned with respect to the expression `element < value` or `comp(element, value)` (which is the case if range is sorted according to binary predicate).
- `std::partition_point` requires that the range is partitioned according to the (unary) predicate.

You can indeed create a predicate to be able to use the other algorithm.

With:

```
const std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

You can do with `lower_bound`:

```
assert(std::is_sorted(v.begin, v.end(), std::less<>));
auto it1 = std::lower_bound(v.begin, v.end(), 5, std::less<>);
```

or with `partition_point`:

```
auto pred = [](int e){ return e < 5; }
assert(std::is_partition(v.begin, v.end(), pred));
auto it2 = std::partition_point(v.begin, v.end(), pred);

assert(it1 == it2); // *it1 = 5
```

Or, with the other side

```
const std::vector<int> v{1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 5, 8, 6};
```

You can do with `partition_point`:

```
auto pred = [](int e){ return e < 5; }
assert(std::is_partition(v.begin, v.end(), pred));
auto it1 = std::partition_point(v.begin, v.end(), pred);
```

or with `lower_bound`:

```
auto pred2 = [](int lhs, int rhs){ return (lhs < 5) > (rhs < 5); }
assert(std::is_sorted(v.begin, v.end(), pred2));
auto it2 = std::lower_bound(v.begin, v.end(), 5, pred2);

assert(it1 == it2); // *it1 == 7
```

Comment: i think this mostly covers it

Comment: `lower_bound` does _not_ require sorted

Comment: @curiousguy That is not what people mean when they say sorted. `[1, 6, 3, 5, 20, 24, 21, 75]` is partitioned by the predicate `x < 10`. It is not sorted. Saying it is sorted by the value of `x < 10` is needlessly confusing.

Answer (score 3):

They are more or less equivalent except that `lower_bound` will use `operator<` to search the elements if a predicate is not provided.* `partition_point` is more generic in that it allows that the range was partitioned according to some generic predicate rather than some predicate against a`value`.

Note that `lower_bound` greatly predates the existence of more generic partitioning concepts in C++.

<sub>*and it's heavily implied that the predicate used in `lower_bound` should satisfy a less-than relationship, though not required</sub>

---

From [alg.partitions]

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class Predicate> 
ForwardIterator partition_point(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Predicate pred);
```

**Requires**: `ForwardIterator’s` value type shall be convertible to `Predicate’s` argument type. `[first, last)` shall be partitioned by `pred`, i.e. all elements that satisfy `pred` shall appear before those that do
not.

**Returns**: An iterator mid such that `all_of(first, mid, pred)` and `none_of(mid, last, pred)` are
both true.

**Complexity**: `O(log(last - first))` applications of `pred`.

And from [lower.bound]

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class T>
ForwardIterator
lower_bound(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
const T& value);

template<class ForwardIterator, class T, class Compare>
ForwardIterator
lower_bound(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
const T& value, Compare comp);
```

**Requires**: The elements `e` of `[first, last)` shall be partitioned with respect to the expression `e < value` or `comp(e, value)`.

**Returns**: The furthermost iterator `i` in the range `[first, last]` such that for every iterator `j` in the
range `[first, i)` the following corresponding conditions hold: `*j < value` or `comp(*j, value) != false`.

**Complexity**: At most `log2(last - first) + O(1)` comparisons.

Comment: does it ? can you link to such a requirement?

Comment: "it does not need to satisfy the requirements of Compare"https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

Comment: @AnkurS From [this `std::lower_bound` refernece](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) regarding the predicate: "binary predicate which returns ​`true` if the first argument is **less than** (i.e. is ordered before) the second." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Actually I revisted the standard and it says `*j < value or comp(*j, value) !=
false.` which allows for a generic predicate used for partitioning

Comment: Doesn't `std::partition_point` also require `[first, last)` to be ordered?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yeah, I conflated the return of `partition_point` with the Requires section.

Comment: `lower_bound` doesn't use `operator<` to partition the range, the range must already be partitioned. Why do you say there's a heavy implication of less-than relationship for the predicate? It just needs to satisfy strict weak ordering.

Comment: @Praetorian: whoops on the misuse of 'partition' there. Also, see [lwg 270](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue270) which states that the strict weak ordering was too strict a requirement and only a partitioning is necessary

Comment: @AndyG You don't point out (though it's in the quoted complexity requirements) that, for `lower_bound`, binary logarithmic complexity is required, whereas for `partition_point`, any logarithm will suffice. (And, no, it's not clear to me when that would be a good thing for the user.)

Comment: "Partitioned" is the same as "increasing", for some ordering relation.